# USB3 Integration and development tools

Tags: .net, usb

Hello : 
I'm planning to start a (Hardware & Software) project which is an USB3 circuit to control a machine and a software application to control it by a computer.
Now i'm doing a research on the software section , and searching for the latest tools and libraries in this connection.

i appreciate any help regarding this,,
thanks

Comment: Your only hope are the libraries shipped _with_ that USB device.

Comment: If i want to use it as a HID (Human interface device) is there any different between USB3 and USB2?

Comment: Please explain what necessary capability USB3 brings to your application which the earlier versions did not provide.

Comment: I admire this posters desire to learn the latest technology, regardless of the uselessness of USB3 with the project.  Perhaps it would lead to something useful in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are simply using USB to "control", USB3 is overkill.  For most "control" (sending commands) full speed (12Mbps) is suitable.  There are many USB2 compliant controllers that you can use.

If you are wanting to transfer data at rates > 1.5Gbps then USB3 might be the solution.  If you do not need the high transfer rates you are better off using one of the main stream micros with built in USB; AVR, ARM variants, Cypress FX2, etc.

Most controllers, these days, will be 2.0 compliant.  USB 2.0 defines 3 speeds, low (1.5Mbps), full (12Mbps), and high (480Mbps).  USB3 defines and additional superhigh speed.

Comment: I want to use USB3 for research purposes, especially on it's data transfer way

Comment: @Alaaeddin : I think there would be little to no difference between USB3 and USB2 for HID devices (answer to questions in separate comments).  If you use one of the common class types, CDC, Mass Storage, HID, etc. you will not need to worry about driver development.  Otherwise use one of the open-source generic interfaces (libusb).  Best of my knowledge, USB3 is really addition of super-high speed and not many other changes.  Mainly a physical interface addition.